# syntastic checker does not work in Gvim in Windows 7

Tags: vim

I installed syntastic according to following link in windows.
https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic.

I ran :SyntasticInfo. Here is the output

[image]

I guess everything is fine & syntastic checker is set for c file with gcc. I purposefully removed semicolons & brackets.But none of the errors got highlighted in my source code file even after saving.

Any suggestions on how to make syntastic checker work ??

Comment: Is gcc in you PATH? You can check by doing `:echo executable('gcc')`.

Comment: it shows output as '1'. Not sure what does that mean.
If I type gcc in command prompt, it asks for the arguments. That means gcc path is added to the system paths. Am I correct ?

Comment: A value of `1` means `gcc` is executable and in you path. Are you using PowerShell or the regular `cmd.exe`? I know syntastic is has issues with PowerShell. You may also want to open an issue with the [Syntastic's issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues). If Syntastic doesn't work out you may be interested in using `:make` to do your linting/compiling. See `:h :make` and `quickfix` for more information

Comment: Thanks @PeterRincker. Now after editing the vimrc files, it shows only 1 error which is at the beginning of file.
Here is my .vimrc configuration.
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list=1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open=1

let g:syntastic_quiet_messages={ "level": [] }

let g:syntastic_aggregate_errors=1

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list=1